# SwiftUI Can't Pass Variable to Higher Order Function Map

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, transform

I have an app with an array of models that contain number fields. I'd like to be
able to sum any given data field. I can do so with map by using the data field
name ($0.cups for example). However I would like to programmatically send in a
variable for "cups" and nothing I have tried works.

Here's some example code. I'd like to pass the field name that I want to total into
the function sumOnAttribute

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var answer: String = ""

    @State private var startingModels = [
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 1, bags: 2, cups: 3),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 11, bags: 12, cups: 13),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 21, bags: 22, cups: 23),
        StartingModel(name: "donna", age: 31, bags: 32, cups: 33),
        StartingModel(name: "elsie", age: 41, bags: 42, cups: 43),
        StartingModel(name: "farah", age: 51, bags: 52, cups: 53)
    ]//some data

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Do Some Math")
                .font(.title)
            Text(answer)
                .font(.headline)
            Button {
                answer = String(sumOnAttribute(filterField: "abe", sumField: "cups"))
            } label: {
                Text("Make it So")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 20))
        }//v
    }//body

    func sumOnAttribute(filterField: String, sumField: String) -> Double {
    
        let filteredAttribute = startingModels.filter({ $0.name == filterField })
    
        //$0.sumField does not work, $0.value(sumField) does not work
        let nums = filteredAttribute.map({ $0.cups })

        let total = nums.reduce(0, +)
        return total
    }
}//struct

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct StartingModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let age: Double
    let bags: Double
    let cups: Double
}//model
```

Seems like this should be simple, but I have not found any answer in a lot of searches.
Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.3, iOS 15.4

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "send in a variable for 'cups'"? Send in where for what purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a `KeyPath` -- it's not a `String` like you're using, but rather a compile-time-safe path to the property you're looking for. An implementation might look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var answer: String = ""

    @State private var startingModels = [
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 1, bags: 2, cups: 3),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 11, bags: 12, cups: 13),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 21, bags: 22, cups: 23),
        StartingModel(name: "donna", age: 31, bags: 32, cups: 33),
        StartingModel(name: "elsie", age: 41, bags: 42, cups: 43),
        StartingModel(name: "farah", age: 51, bags: 52, cups: 53)
    ]//some data

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Do Some Math")
                .font(.title)
            Text(answer)
                .font(.headline)
            Button {
                answer = String(sumOnAttribute(filterField: "abe", sumField: \.cups))
            } label: {
                Text("Make it So")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 20))
        }//v
    }//body

    func sumOnAttribute(filterField: String, sumField: KeyPath<StartingModel,Double>) -> Double {
        let filteredAttribute = startingModels.filter({ $0.name == filterField })
        return filteredAttribute.map({ $0[keyPath:sumField] }).reduce(0, +)
    }
}//struct
```

If you really wanted to use a `String`, you could consider using `@dynamicMemberLookup`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/55/how-to-use-dynamic-member-lookup-in-swift

Comment: This KeyPath approach will work great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not clear what you want, maybe you could try something like this, "...to pass the field name that I want to total into the function sumOnAttribute...":

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var namefield: String = ""  // <-- here
    @State private var sumfield: String = ""   // <-- here
    @State private var answer: String = ""
    
    @State private var startingModels = [
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 1, bags: 2, cups: 3),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 11, bags: 12, cups: 13),
        StartingModel(name: "abe", age: 21, bags: 22, cups: 23),
        StartingModel(name: "donna", age: 31, bags: 32, cups: 33),
        StartingModel(name: "elsie", age: 41, bags: 42, cups: 43),
        StartingModel(name: "farah", age: 51, bags: 52, cups: 53)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            TextField("name field", text: $namefield).border(.red) // <-- here
            TextField("sum field", text: $sumfield).border(.red)   // <-- here
            Text("Do Some Math")
                .font(.title)
            Text(answer)
                .font(.headline)
            Button {
                answer = String(sumOnAttribute(filterField: namefield, sumField: sumfield)) // <-- here
            } label: {
                Text("Make it So")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
    }
    
    func sumOnAttribute(filterField: String, sumField: String) -> Double {
        let filteredAttribute = startingModels.filter{ $0.name == filterField }
        // -- here
        var nums: [Double] = []
        switch sumField {
          case "cups": nums = filteredAttribute.map{ $0.cups }
          case "bags": nums = filteredAttribute.map{ $0.bags }
          case "age": nums = filteredAttribute.map{ $0.age }
          default: break
        }
        return nums.reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks working dog. This does indeed work, however for this project I think the Keypath option from jnpdx would be better because I am using a rather large public database with over 40 cases for the switch. I'd rather not not hard code all of that.